# Gather data on the same statistic across modules in OMNeT++

Tags: simulation, omnet++

I am using OMNeT++ as my simulation engine for an arbitrary network topology simulation. I have created different custom OMNeT modules to simulate different entities in my simulation. I am also using OMNeT `signals` and `statistics` for result gathering.

I am wondering whether I can collect data originating from different modules with separate signals but to be gathered, processed, and recorded in the output file by the same statistic?

I know I could probably get away with just registering and using separate statistics per module but as the [documentation states](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:signal-based-statistics) that the resulting collection and recording is happening on a higher level in the OMNeT inheritance hierarchy and thus across different instances of a module, I am thinking that this should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out, I can get the intended result by retrieving a reference to the module instance that has created the `statistic` and `signal` and emitting the value that I want, even when handling an event on a different module.

A relevant code snippet below:

```
auto ref = (ModuleClass *)getParentModule()->getSubmodule("ModuleName");
if (ref == NULL)
{
    //check successful instance retrieval
}

ref->emit(ref->relaventSignal, ValueToEmit);
```